# How do I activate the Red Trinity in Oogie's?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

I activate all heartless spawning areas, clear everything out (I sealed the keyhole), and still the triangle command to activate the Red Trinity in Oogie's won't show up. Is this normal, or is it a bug that I'll have to wait for Square-Enix to patch?

Comment: It's been awhile, so I'm not sure about the progression, but have you completed Deep Jungle (Tarzan)?

Comment: Im pretty much now about to face dragon Maleficent...

Comment: Just to check... do you have Jack Skellington in your party?

Answer (score 1):

The Red Trinity that has been moved to the gate near to Oogie's Manor appears to be somewhat glitchy. According to [this forum thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/684080-kingdom-hearts-hd-15-remix/67251382), some steps to try are:

> You may have to beat the mini-boss in the area and/or leave the room and come back before it'll work.

In that thread, leaving and re-entering helped the poster be able to use that red trinity mark.